# Ubuntu/Kubuntu 16.04: I would like a uid < 1000 so that it matches an old nfs mount

Tags: users, nfs

Using 16.04.  I've converted to Kubuntu desktop by adding `kubuntu-desktop` and `kubuntu-full`.

I want to change my UID with `usermod` to 566 in order to play better with that UID for my account on another machine that exports nfs.  When I do this, the account no longer shows up for login.

I've googled this extensively and have tried editing `/etc/login.defs` and `/etc/lightdm/users.conf`, setting the min UID and GUID to be 500 instead of 1000.  What am I missing? The
account will simply not show up.  Also, if I can just get the nfs mount to use my name instead of UID, that would be good, but it's an old 8.04 Ubuntu box so I think it may not be possible.

Comment: It's usually better to do mapping. https://serverfault.com/questions/514118/mapping-uid-and-gid-of-local-user-to-the-mounted-nfs-share explains it in some detail.

Comment: The server is older, ubuntu 8.04.  It doesn't have the file /sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping I actually remember doing this locally on my previous 16.04 machine, but I can't remember what I had to change to get the user to show up in the login manager.